# Restore navigation bar with and height with bootstrap link

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm incorporating bootstrap into my site, and there is a noticeable difference in the layout, particularly the navigation grid item div. This is the html code for the navigation bar:

```
<div id="container-i" class="container">
   <div class="item logo">
    <h1><a class="myName"
      href="index.html">BROOKLYN</a></h1>
   </div>
   <div class="item links">
    <ul class="navigation">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about-me.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>
        <li><a href="music.html">Music</a></li>
        <li><a href="tours.html">Tours</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="item menu">
    <div class="menu-btn">
     <div class="btn-mid"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And this is the css code for the container:

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

When I add the line `<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` to the header the width and height change. Here are two screenshots showing the results before and after:
[image: Navigation Before]
[image: Navigation After]

I'm aware that 'container' is a class in bootstrap, so I can kind of adjust the with by changing the class to 'container-fullwidth', but even so, I still can't change the height and re-center the content vertically. I've already tried altering the style with the height attribute.

I'm trying to keep everything as ordered and as consistent and as centered as I can because I want this to be as professional as possible, so is there a way for me to reverse the changes after adding the code?

Answer (score 0):

boostrap has its own classes sometimes it matches with your classes too.
so for that you have to remove bootstrap class from your html and custom class and add your css to that class.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out for the display, some of the bootstrap class styles overwrite the ones that I write. So to counter this, make sure that the custom css file is declared after the bootstrap css file like this:

And make sure that each element in the layout has a class to specify what the changes apply to. Your changes should then overwrite bootstrap designs.